# Putting extra brackets around equation adds whitespace to next line

Tags: spacing, brackets, braces, scoping

As the title says, when I add an extra pair of `{}` brackets to the equation environment (on the outside), it adds a whitespace about the width of a space to the next line. Adding `\noindent` to the next line does not remove the space. Really I was trying to localize the scope of `\medmuskip=3mu` to the single equation with the brackets (see code below), which seems to have worked, but the whitespace is annoying me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
{\medmuskip=3mu
\begin{equation}
    Ax=b
\end{equation}}
Hello % there's an extra space before Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noindent` won't work because this isn't the start of a new paragraph.  `\ignorespaces` should wprk, but the easiest fix is to add a `%` after the closing brace, as stated in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For eliminating white space on beginning of next paragraph add `%` after curly braces:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
{\medmuskip=3mu
\begin{equation}
    Ax=b
\end{equation}
}% <--- added
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, you deleted and then restored the same answer that I gave.... I'll remove mine since you beat me by three minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The closing bracket  seems to start a new paragraph. Add `\noindent`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
{\medmuskip=3mu
\begin{equation}
    Ax=b
\end{equation}}\noindent
Hello % there's an extra space before Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: hm, it seems that it sufficient to add `%` e.g.: `\end{equation}}%`. It not start new paragraph but insert spurious space (of one letter).

Comment: You're right. Actually , adding anything *immediately* after the bracket works. I'll remove my answer, as it's not the real explanation. Please write your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the parameter *inside* `equation`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
\begin{equation}
\medmuskip=20mu
    Ax=b+c
\end{equation}
Hello

\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
\begin{equation}
    Ax=b+c
\end{equation}
Hello

\end{document}
```

[image]

This wouldn't work with `amsmath` alignments; here's a workaround: the optional argument to `local` must be assignments, the mandatory argument is the environment to use internally.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{local}{O{}m}
 {#1\csname #2\endcsname}
 {\csname end#2\endcsname\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
\begin{local}[\medmuskip=20mu]{equation}
    Ax=b+c
\end{local}
Hello

\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
\begin{local}[\medmuskip=20mu]{align}
    Ax&=b+c\\
    Bx&=d
\end{local}
Hello

\noindent Paragraph stuff lalala.
\begin{align}
    Ax&=b+c\\
    Bx&=d
\end{align}
Hello

\end{document}
```

[image]